# How to determine the current version of ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to get the current version of ASP.NET MVC in code? Reflecting on MVC assemblies is needed? Any new IIS server variables? Some property to read in HTTP context?

Comment: By 'cool' do you mean 'efficient' or 'convoluted?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which version of MVC am I using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930217/which-version-of-mvc-am-i-using)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Via Reflection:

```
typeof (Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: very nice!
I'm checked MvcHandler.GetMvcVersionString() in mvc source code(but private method,regret..).

Comment: Can also check the name to confirm it is in fact an mvc app: typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Name, or both at same time: typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().FullName.

Answer (score 185):

1. Go to your References folder
2. Look for `System.Web.Mvc`
3. Right Click on it
4. Click Properties
5. Look at the Version property.

This is most likely your version but the GAC may play a role in messing you around.

Comment: try adding it again but make a backup

Answer (score 23):

Open the packages.config in your solution explorer..

Then look for ASP.NET MVC package ID, as follows:

id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net452"

Answer (score 6):

**At runtime-**

```
string mvcVersion = typeof (Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

**At design time-**

- Go to your reference folder
- look for system.web.mvc
- Right Click on it
- Click Properties Look at the Version property

.

Comment: I don't understand at first in `Create new project` window above asp templates were written 4.6 but my MVC reference assembly is version 5 :|

Comment: What exactly does this answer add to the thread ? You just copied other answers.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance you do not have access to the code and/or want to determine the version of ASP.NET that has been deployed on a machine, you can do the following (from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-059)):

> **How do I determine which version of ASP.NET MVC is installed on my
> system?**
>
> For MVC 4.0, MVC 5.0, or MVC 5.1 you should have deployed the
> affected binary (System.Web.MVC.dll) with your application. Check your
> application’s bin folder for the version of the binary. For MVC 2.0,
> MVC 3.0, or MVC 4.0, refer to the Add or Remove Programs control panel
> item for the version of MVC installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check version of [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/) nuget package installed in your project.

You can use Package Manager Console:

```
Get-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of finding the MVC version for ASP net CORE projects by adding small code to your Home Controller. Hope this will be helpful.

Go to the Project Controller folder, open 'HomeController.cs' file. In HomeController.cs file,  there is an Index Method with the return type of ActionResult/IActionResults. Just change the Method type from ActionResult to string and write the code, given below, into that method.

return typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString ();

Run your project, You can see the MVC version used in your project on the home page.

Answer (score -2):

Use NuGet package MvcDiagnostics that you can install. Create an MVC "hello world" or some other basic program, then install this package. The installation will prompt for the project to add a file to. Confirm and you should see MvcDiagnostics.aspx added to your project. Right click on this file in the solution viewer, then choose "View in browser". You should then see a nice page with all your assembly information. Mine looks like the following:

```
Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Diagnostics Information

This page is designed to help diagnose common errors related to mismatched or conflicting ASP.NET MVC binaries. If a known issue is identified, it will be displayed below in red text.

For questions or problems with ASP.NET MVC or this utility, please visit the ASP.NET MVC forums at http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx.

Environment Information

Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
.NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.34209 (32-bit)
Web server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Integrated pipeline: True
Worker process: iisexpress.exe
AppDomain: Homogenous = True, FullTrust = True

ASP.NET MVC Assembly Information (System.Web.Mvc.dll)

Assembly version: ASP.NET MVC 4 RTM (4.0.20710.0)
Full name: System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Code base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Mvc/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Mvc.dll
Deployment: GAC-deployed

ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly Information (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll)

An ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly has not been loaded into this application. A download for this version of ASP.NET MVC Futures is not available. Pre-release versions of the MVC Futures assembly are no longer available once that version of ASP.NET MVC has gone RTM.

All Loaded Assemblies

71 assemblies are loaded.

A_65e81fd0_eb37_47d8_aba0_baece822c7ad, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
App_global.asax.1h_47vyd, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
App_Web_rnug5pva, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BasicAuthentication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=12.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing, Version=12.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Workflow.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Workflow.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
WebGrease, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```