# Which version of MVC am I using?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, version

I can't find it for some reason, feeling a little dumb. How do I know? I'm using .net 4 with VS2010.

Comment: So glad you asked this question :)

Comment: for some reason I felt little dumb too ;)

Comment: This question is a duplicate in [stackoverflow][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008704/how-to-determine-the-current-version-of-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This *should* be more obvious, and easier to find.  None-the-less, a useful combination of answer-and-question.

Comment: Over a decade later your "dumb" question has 400 up votes.  In 2021 I had the same "dumb" question.  Just goes to say there are no "dumb" questions.  Thank You for asking the question so I can find it here and not have to ask my own "dumb" question.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Open web.config file and find the System.Web.Mvc assembly definition:

```
assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 ..."
```

It's an MVC3 as you see. Via web you can use [MvcDiagnostics](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx) which is similar to `phpinfo()` functionality in PHP.

Comment: For me, it appears in web.config as ` <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />`. This is showing MVC version 5. I checked by the other two methods below.

Comment: I found mine in **packages.config**, not web.config.

Comment: This isn't always present in all MVC projects; it may be version dependent and Visual Studio dependent; it is possibly project-dependent as well.

Comment: Note that as of MVC6 you will find it in project.json under `dependencies` -> `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"`

Comment: You can check multiple ways here: 
http://www.codingfusion.com/post/Multiple-ways-to-know-which-version-of-MVC-am-I-using-in-net-mvc

Answer (score 262):

Select the System.Web.Mvc assembly in the "References" folder in the solution explorer.  Bring up the properties window (F4) and check the Version

[image: Reference Properties]

Comment: I prefer this method, because sometimes the web.config doesn't list the System.Web.MVC assembly.

Comment: I was always confused about the runtime version and the Version. Was not sure which one was the one I was supposed to look at.

Comment: @Farax Runtime version is .net CLR version under which the assembly is compiled. Its helpful to let you know the minimum .net runtime version you can use / to the min version you can down grade your project so that the assembly still works.

Answer (score 27):

Another solution is to search for mvc in nuget (right click on your MVC project in visual studio and select "Manage Nuget Packages").

This will show you the version currently installed -[image]

And it'll also allow you to update the MVC version -
[image]

Comment: Best choice for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

```
typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Gives the current version programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

I had this question because there is no MVC5 template in VS 2013. We had to select ASP.NET web application and then choose MVC from the next window.

You can check in the System.Web.Mvc dll's properties like in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I chose System.web.MVC from reference folder and right clicked on it to go property window where I could see version of MVC. This solution works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well just use **MvcDiagnostics.aspx** It shows lots information about current MVC instalations, and also helps with debuging. You can find it in MVC source or just Google for it.

Comment: Other answers are good for directing people to the right part of the solution (web.config, or the `References`). This answer shows us how to see it at runtime. `MvcDiagnostics` is not part of a standard MVC installation, but it's worth installing (with nuget). See http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx/. It's *very* easy to install and then run :)

Comment: I hate when people say "just Google for it".

Comment: @mac10688 https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDiagnostics and http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx/

Comment: @mac10688 it's even better when Google itself brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer open packages.config and find Microsoft.AspNet.MVC:

package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461"

From the above we can see it's an Asp.Net MVC 5.2.3 Version.

Moreover packages.config file also helps us to track all the installed packages with their respective versions.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET" folder.
You will see "ASP.NET MVC 4" or something like that.
To know detail navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET{your MVC version}\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll"
Right click and see the version.

Answer (score 0):

In Mvc You can do it by opening Web.config file
it comes under bottom of your project file