# Html.Raw is null

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm in trouble here. In my view i have the following code:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert)) { 
    <div class="alert">@Html.Raw(alert)</div>
}
```

But an exception of type `NullReferenceException` is being thrown saying that the Html property is null. How i can solve this?

OBS: My view page inherits from a class that by their turn inherits from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage`

// WEBCONFIG

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you use `@Html.Raw(alert)`

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? The `Raw` method was added in MVC 3.

Comment: @Kane Yes, i also get the error!

Comment: @Guffa I've updated the post with the assembly section of the web config. Is it right?

Comment: Do the assembly references in your main web.config and the web.config in your Views folder differ?

Comment: @mnatan.brito: I don't think that's even from the right `web.config`, I think that there should be a `System.Web.Mvc` in there, which should show what version you are using. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930217/which-version-of-mvc-am-i-using

Comment: @TimBJames I don't have another web config in my app.

Comment: @Guffa I didn't get it.

Comment: My project is a website project. There is some issue with this?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't get the solution, so i changed the code to:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert)) {    
    <div class="alert">@(new HtmlString(alert))</div>
}
```

Razor doesn't encode HtmlString. So it worked fine.